# iOS 6 and localization of storyboards

Tags: xcode, ios6, localization, xcode4

I've converted my project to a minimum SDK 6, and switched to using the base localization.  I am in the USA so using English as my base, so I do not have the storyboard translated to en.  The storyboard is in the Base.lproj folder.  There is a .strings file in all of the language folders except English.

I want to confirm that I don't (shouldn't) have a translation for the language I use.  Correct?

But my real question is, how do the .strings files in the other language files get created?  The translators at my company want the English version for they to use in their tools, so I will send them the Localizable.strings from Base, but do I need to run ibtool to extract the strings from the storyboard?  I want to make sure I'm following the best practices, and to make sure I'm being efficient and not doing too many extra unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 0):

Following step follow to implement localisation.

1. Select Xcode---->Build Setting
2. Localisation-->Select Language.
3. Add language.